# How to compare types (including ref-qualifiers) in a parameter pack and the types of std::function parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, std-function, template-argument-deduction

I'm storing an `std::function` inside a variadic class template (passed in the constructor of the class).

While doing so, I want to check that the types of the `std::function` parameters are the same as the types within the parameter pack of the class template. Here is an example:

```
template<typename... T>
class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(std::function<void(T...)> f)
        : func(std::move(f)) {
        // static_assert(...) How to formulate the static_assert here?
    }

    std::function<void(T...)> func;    
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> fooA([](int& a){}); // does not compile 
    Foo<int&> fooB([](int a){}); // should not compile, but does
    
    Foo<int&> fooC([](int& a){}); // should compile 
}
```

If a class `Foo<int&>` is defined with a reference type, I'd like to make sure that the lambda also takes an `int` by reference and not by value.

The other way around (`Foo<int>` and lambda with an `int&`) already does not compile as that lambda cannot be converted to a function taking an `int` by value.

Using a `static_assert()`, I tried to ensure that the type of the parameter in the lambda matches the type given as a template parameter to `Foo`.

So far, I have tried unwrapping the function arguments:

```
template<typename... T>
struct ID {};

template<typename Func>
struct Unwrap;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Unwrap<R(Args...)> {
    using ArgsType = ID<Args...>;
};

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Unwrap<std::function<R(Args...)>> 
    : Unwrap<R(Args...)> {};

...
static_assert(std::is_same<typename Unwrap<std::function<void(T...)>>::ArgsType, ID<T...>>::value, "");
...
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want? (Does it even make sense for me to think about such a check on my end, or should someone using my `class Foo` make sure, that he provides a lambda with the correct parameter types?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use C++17... what about using the [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) defined for `std::function` to check that the `std::function` deduced for the argument of the constructor is exactly the same of `func`?

I mean... what about as follows?

```
template <typename... T>
struct Foo
 {
   template <typename L>
      Foo (L && l) : func{ std::forward<L>(l) }
    {
      using T1 = decltype(func);
      using T2 = decltype(std::function{std::forward<L>(l)});

      static_assert( std::is_same_v<T1, T2>, "a better failure message, please" );
    }

   std::function<void(T...)> func;    
 };
```

Using this `Foo` you get

```
//Foo<int> fooA([](int& a){}); // compilation error (assigning func) 
//Foo<int&> fooB([](int a){}); // compilation error (static_assert failure)

Foo<int&> fooC([](int& a){}); // compile
```

**--- EDIT ---**

The OP observe that

> `Foo<void(int&)> fooD([](auto&) {});` would not compile

Unfortunately, this solution impose a `std::function` parameters CTAD deduction, so gives a compilation error when the argument is a generic lambda.

We can SFINAE deactivate the `static_assert()` in case the `std::function` is not deducible

```
constexpr std::false_type Bar (...);

template <typename L>
constexpr auto Bar (L && l)
   -> decltype( std::function{std::forward<L>(l)}, std::true_type{} );

template <typename... T>
struct Foo
 {
   template <typename L>
      Foo (L && l) : func{ std::forward<L>(l) }
    {
      if constexpr ( decltype(Bar(std::forward<L>(l)))::value == true )
       {
         using T1 = decltype(func);
         using T2 = decltype(std::function{std::forward<L>(l)});

         static_assert( std::is_same_v<T1, T2>, "a better message, please" );
       }
    }

   std::function<void(T...)> func;    
 };
```

So

```
Foo<int &> fooF([](auto &){});
```

become compilable.

Continue to gives an error a generic lambda receiving a generic reference when a value is requested

```
//Foo<int>   fooD([](auto &){}); // compilation error (assigning func)
```

because remain the error assigning `func`.

The problem is that, deactivating the test, the following code compile

```
Foo<int &> fooE([](auto){}); // compile (!)
```

and I don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. One thing I'd like to point out is that `Foo<void(int&)> fooD([](auto&) {});` would not compile, as the template arguments for `std::function` could not be deducible. This gets lost due to the forwarding reference, I think.

Comment: @maro213_ - Unfortunately, you're right: this is a limit of this solution because a generic lambda can't be deduced from the `std::function`s CTAD.

Comment: @maro213_ - I've expanded the answer to show how to disable the `static_assert` when a `std::function` isn't deducible. Now `Foo<void(int&)> fooD([](auto&) {});` compile. The problem is that also `Foo<void(int&)> fooD([](auto) {});`